# ¿Cómo mostrar las imágenes en un buscador de Posts en Symfony 5 en una petición AJAX?

Tags: symfony

Estoy programando un buscador de posts en symfony 5 y al hacer la petición por ajax, se muestran todos los datos pero no las imágenes.

Estoy tratando de que al buscar publicaciones con imágenes, se muestren en plantilla twig.

En mi controlador es una petición sencilla a la base de datos, las imágenes están guardadas en la carpeta public.

Controlador:

```
/**
* @Route("search_posts", options={"expose"=true}, name="search_posts")
*/
public function search_posts(Request $request): Response {
   if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $buscar = $request->request->get('data');
       $titulo = $em->getRepository(Posts:: class)->buscador_posts($buscar);
       return $this->json($titulo);
   }
   //return $this->render('$0.html.twig', []);
}
```

En el archivo ajax **`public/jquery/buscador_posts.js`**.

---

El problema está cuando extraigo el nombre de la foto pero al colocar la ruta de la foto no me aparece, he pensado en poner al nombre del archivo js con twig. Pero lo he probado y tampoco me funciona.

```
$('#form_search').keyup(function (e) {
    var Ruta_buscador = Routing.generate('search_posts');
    var texto = $('#form_search').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Ruta_buscador,
        data: ({ data: texto }),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var mostrar = '';
            $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                mostrar +=
                    "<div class='card mb-4' style='width: 44rem;'>" +
                    "<img class='card-img-top img-fluid' id='img_id' src='" + value.foto + "' alt='Card image cap'></img>" +
                    "<div class='card-body'>" +
                    "<h3 class='card-title'>" + value.titulo + "</h3>" +
                    "<p class='card-text'></p>" +
                    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>Ver Más →</a>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='card-footer text-muted'>" +
                    "Posted on " + value.fecha_publicacion + " by <a href='#'>" + value.nombre + "</a>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>";
            });

            $('#titulo').html(mostrar);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: un ejemplo del valor de `value.foto` cual sería?

Comment: el valor es sacado de la base de datos como imagen.jpg. Pero no se como hacer para que se muestre la imagen. Concateno el valor con la ruta public/uploads/photos, pero no se muestra la imágen.

Comment: no... si la ruta dentro del mismo servidor es public/uploads/photo y tu archivo index.php está en public... lo debes es concatenar con /uploads asi: `"<img class='card-img-top img-fluid' id='img_id' src='/uploads/" + value.foto + "' alt='Card image cap'></img>"`

Comment: estoy con symfony, mi archivo index.php está en la carpeta template y el archivo ajax está en la carpeta public.

Comment: ya lo probaste concatenando /uploads?

Comment: Lo probé y me funcionó, gracias Pipe.